# cakephp : update another table's data on update

Tags: mysql, cakephp, updates

I have these tables

users table :

```
id  lastname    firstname   email                   company             city        phone
1   Doe         John        doe.john@email.com      somecompany         New-York    85505040
```

companies table :

```
id  name            adress              city        phone
1   somecompany     1881 Paper Street   New-York    85505042
2   anothercompany  18  Digital Street  New-York    87505040
```

companies_users table :

```
id  user_id companies_id
1   1       2
```

When I update a user(changing the company they belong to), the companies_users table updates the companies_id. The cakephp app is something I'm inhereting so I don't find everything easily.

What I want to add, is to able to update a user's company when I change something in the companies table : if I change the name, I want the name to change in users table as well.

CompaniesController edit :

```
 public function edit($id = null){
    $companie = $this->Companies->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        if ($this->Companies->save($companie)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your company has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your company.'));
    }
```

}

UsersController edit :

```
 public function edit($id = null){
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data,['associated' => ['Companies']]);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Your user has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to update your user.'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $user);

        $companies = $this->Users->Companies->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('companies'));
}
```

Comment: Why is there a company name in the users table to begin with? Smells like insufficient normalization.

Comment: @ndm well yeah, there's some questionnable stuff. I'do with the company id, but then if I want display my table I'll need to get the company name so I don't know. I actually added a company_id column to my users table, but don't know how I'll collect the name instead of the idea in the display

Comment: ndm is right, if your models were properly associated you would naturally retrieve the company info (like name) when you get a user, no need for duplication of data.  You have a badly-structured database on your hands, the problem isn't with cake.

Comment: Yeah I get that but no I don't naturally retrieve the info.

Comment: You'll retrieve the info when you [**contain the association**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#eager-loading-associations-via-contain) (`$this->Users->get($id, ['contain' => ['Companies']])`), which would be the natural thing to do with proper relations set up. Surely it's possible to update user data when updating company data, but that's heading in a totally wrong direction, so if possible, scratch that from your todo list, and instead rethink the database schema, properly normalize it, and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Here is easy way to update both table:
first create the foreign key in company table ***user_id(int)(11) NULL***
When you update User table:

```
public function edit_user($id = null)
{
   // check if id in empty or not
  if(empty($id))
  {
    // redirect to list page
  }

   $this->User->id = $id;
     if ($this->request->is('put') || $this->request->is('post')) {
     if ($this->User->save($this->request->data))
     {
         $this->Companies = ClassRegistry::init('Companies');
         $comp_id = $this->Companies->find('first',array(
            'contain' => array(),
            'fields' => array('Companies.id'),
            'conditions' => array('Companies.user_id' => $id),
          ));
         $this->Companies->id = $comp_id['Companies']['id'];
         $this->Companies->savefield('name',$this->request->data['User']['company']);
          // success message place here
     }
    else
     {
       // false message write
  }

      }
}
```

**Use Same Method for Company Table Update**

Comment: thanks, do you have any idea how I can display the correct company name when displaying the users table in html ? I'm displaying the users table in an html table through a foreach loop. So with the foreign key company_id in users table, there should be a way to get the name, right ?

Comment: @Nolan.K The shown code is for CakePHP 2.x, please don't accept such answers, this will only confuse future readers.

Comment: Yes, you can user belongs to in your user model and in your controller in user Compny model as contain fields.